# python TypeError: 'NoneType'

Tags: python

The following code returns an error on line 6 of type : TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

What is wrong?

```
def insertAtList(name, score, H):
    E = [score, name]
    i = len(H) - 1
    if H[i] != None:
        print("fail")
    while H[i-1][0] < E[0] or H[i-1] == None:
        H[i] = H[i-1]
        i -= 1
    H[i] = E
    for c in range (0,len(H) - 1):
        print(H[c])

def testq4():
    H = [[940, "Mike"], [880, "Rob"], [830, "Jill"], [790, "Paul"],
        [750, "Anna"], [660, "Rose"], [650, "Jack"], None, None, None]
    insertAtList("Mark",675,H)

testq4()
```

Comment: use is when checking None,  `if H[i] is not None` etc.. and swap the order in your while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to swap the order of the operands in your while-loop condition. The `or` checks the conditions from left to right, and stops evaluating when it has found one `True` value. That's what you'll want to do when you find out that `H[i-1]` is `None`. Currently, if `H[i-1]` is `None`, you're still trying to evaluate `H[i-1][0]`, which does not exist.

Try it like this:

```
# ...
if H[i] is not None:
    print("fail")
while H[i-1] is None or H[i-1][0] < E[0]:
    H[i] = H[i-1]
    i -= 1
# ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear. You are accessing a None-value, trying to treat it as a list. And the reason for that is that you *first* try & access it that way *before* you test if it is None. So you need to revert your conditions in the while-loop. On top of that, checking for None is not done using the != or == operator, but the "is" and "is not" operator, because None is a singleton. Last but not least, you should consider to replace your code with something that leverages the builtin capabilities of list-sorting:

```
 def insertAtList(name, score, highscores):
     highscores.append([score, name])
     highscores.sort(key=lambda entry: 0 if entry is None else entry, reverse=True)



 H = [[940, "Mike"], [880, "Rob"], [830, "Jill"], [790, "Paul"],
         [750, "Anna"], [660, "Rose"], [650, "Jack"], None, None, None]
 insertAtList("Mark",675,H)
 print H
```

Comment: "You should throw away your code and replace it with this" is not really helpful, is it?

Comment: I'm sorry but this is a CSc exercise and I can't use python specific functions. This was just some implementation of pseudocode for inserting into arrays. Nevertheless +1 for your answer.

Comment: @Joost yup, the phrasing was harsher than it should have been, I corrected that. I still think the code is bad, but if it's an assignment, there is little arguing. The OP might still learn something ;)

Comment: Note that while there's definitely something to say for using builtins, @Panayiotis' solution does use the advantage of having an already sorted list rather than simply appending and re-sorting. There's some educational value to that, I'd argue.

Comment: Well, there is a *lot* we can discuss about this obviously (setting aside the educational aspects here). Maintaining a rather complicated piece of code which only works under a unchecked invariant would be something I'd shy away from in production code, unless performance is actually hampered by this. And *if* there was a case for leveraging the sortedness, I'd still go for the standard library bisect instead. Because reading code is done more often than writing, and then I can glance instead of having to deep-dive here. YMMV.